# Why was the deadly boxing match between Butch & Willis not shown on screen?

Tags: plot-explanation, pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction* (1994), only the radio commentary of the deadly boxing match between Butch and Willis (where Willis died in the ring) is heard, but it isn't shown on screen. Why so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it's not needed for the story for the match to be shown. Also a boxing match would break the "initimacy" of showing only few people on the screen. There is no need to show the match as the radio commentary fill the gap perfectly while allowing the viewers to not get too exited before the "french movie" type of car ride.